# Notifying drupal user on publishing

Tags: notifications

I'd like to be able to notify a fellow publisher within the drupal permissions group that a new piece of content relevant to their page has been published. NOT an end-user alert, but just an internal alert on Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use case for the [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module, which can be used to add notifications to any **menu item** and/or **menu tab** of your choice. Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Provides a method for adding iOS-style badges to menu items. (see screenshot)
>
> [image]

Because of how it integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you basically reduce the solution specific to your question here to something like this:

- Create an appropriate view about "*new pieces of content relevant to their page has been published*" (as in your question).
- And create a menu item or menu tab for it.
- Grant access to that view for those users who fit "*a fellow publisher within the Drupal permissions group*" (as in your question).
- Perform the required [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) configuration to tell it which menu item/tab you used for it in your view.

Refer to the video [Defining Menu Badges with Views in Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoZQNg5QOI) (from the module maintainer) for more details. It shows a scenario that might be close to what you'd want to implement also.

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...